# Can not import conda environment due to dyld: Library not loaded

Tags: r, conda

I exported `conda` environment on `OSX` computer with `conda list --explicit > spec-file.txt`. Then, after several days I tried importing the environment with `conda create --name myenv --file spec-file.txt` on another computer that also runs `OSX` but one link seemed to be broken:

https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-64/r-base-3.5.1-h4fe35fd_1.tar.bz2

It is writing that the resource is missing. So, I deleted this line from the `spec-file.txt` and successfully imported the environment. Then, since I still needed to use `R` inside `conda` I tried installing it:

```
conda install -c r r-base
```

After the installation `R` can not be launched giving the error:

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libreadline.6.2.dylib
>     Referenced from: /anaconda3/envs/rmain/lib/R/lib/libR.dylib
>     Reason: image not found

I searched over the web and found the link:

https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/3113

Where it was suggested to change `pcre` installation. I tried it, switched to `8.39` version, but the error stayed the same. In the exported environment `pcre` is `8.41`, so actually it may not be the problem here since the other environment that I used for generating the `spec-file.txt` is working perfect. So, either I need a way to change the broken link in the `spec-file.txt` to the correct one or to somehow fix the `R` and I am not sure how to do either.

> Update

I tried substituting the link in the `spec-file.txt` for the following one:

https://conda.anaconda.org/r/osx-64/r-base-3.5.1-h539fb6c_1.tar.bz2

Then I reinstalled the environment but the issue remained.